# How to pass values from Lists (java.util.list) to paint method?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

i have problem concerning to  XML and java.util.List. In my script Iam able to parse XML file from input  and System writes me e.g. [124, 123], [123, 130] (according to this what is in the input file.) but my question is - how to pass values from xList and yList to paint method?  What do  I Have to do?  set/get value?  Or maybe is there a better way how to do it. Thanks

part of my script:

```
    try
        {

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        MyDefaultHandler handler = new MyDefaultHandler();
        saxParser.parse(filechooser.getSelectedFile(), handler);
        System.out.println(handler.getXList() + ", " + handler.getYList());
    }
    catch (Exception exe)
    {
        exe.printStackTrace();
    }
    }    
        }

    class MyDefaultHandler extends DefaultHandler
{
    final List<Integer> xList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    final List<Integer> yList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    boolean xele = false;
    boolean yele = false;

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
    {

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("X"))
        {
            xele = true;
        }

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            yele = true;
        }


    }

    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException
    {

        if (xele)
        {
            System.out.println("X value : " + new String(ch, start, length));
            xele = false;
            xList.add(Integer.parseInt(new String(ch, start, length)));
        }

        if (yele)
        {
            System.out.println("Y value : " + new String(ch, start, length));
            yele = false;
            yList.add(Integer.parseInt(new String(ch, start, length)));

        }
;
    }

    final List<Integer> getXList()
    {
        return xList;

    }

    final List<Integer> getYList()
    {
        return yList;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you question and expecting that the lists are of the same length, you'll need something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<xList.size(); i++) { paint(xList.get(i),yList.get(i)); }
```